# When iterating through a feature in my data-set I am getting IndexError: index 22437 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22437

Tags: python, dataframe

I am grouping the value in one of the features in my data-set according to another feature which has only 4 unique values. total observation in this dataset are 22438.

Now while iterating through a feature I am getting this error-

```
IndexError: index 22437 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22437
```

I have loaded my dataframe in df. here I have to append the values from df[:,1:2] into the values( which are lists) according to the keys.

here is my code:

```
    od = {'2013J':[], '2014J':[], '2013B':[], '2014B':[]}
    od = OrderedDict(od)
    df = df.values
    for up in od.keys():
        i=0
        for cp in df[:,1:2]:
            i=i+1
            if(cp==up):
                od[up].append(df[i,2])


    print(od)
```

what is the problem with the code? what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

You're initialising `i = 0` and then immediately incrementing it by `1` before using it, so on each iteration it will be 1 larger than you expect. On the final iteration, `i` will be equal to the size of the array axis and since arrys start at 0 in python, this will cause an `IndexError`.

You can either initialise `i = -1`, put `i = i + 1` (or `i += 1`) at the bottom of the loop block or, the best solution, use the `enumerate` function like so:

```
for up in od.keys():
        for i, cp in enumerate(df[:, 1:2]):
            if cp == up:
                od[up].append(df[i, 2])
```